# How can I get Onboard (the screen keyboard) to stop launching every time I log in?

Tags: onboard, startup-applications

For some strange reason (i.e. I don't have a tablet computer) Onboard, the on-screen keyboard, starts every time I log in. I've checked Startup Applications, but it's not listed there. What could be making it start like this, and how can I get it to stop?

Comment: When you say that Onboard starts every time you log in, do you happen to mean it appears when you are unlocking the screen? (Because that's an issue I _have_ encountered, but it might not be what you're having).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this bug is back in precise (tried using update manager, didn't work)
This is the only solution I found:

Open a terminal window and type the following commands:

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart
sudo rm onboard-autostart.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug: [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/bugs/858988)

You can use Update Manager for fix

Answer (score 2):

Let's try two things here. Open the Terminal application and type these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled false
gsettings set apps.onboard xembed-onboard false
```

The first command toggles whether the screen keyboard should be visible, just to make sure it is *supposed* to be turned off. That is the same as the option under System Settings / Universal Access.

The second command makes sure OnBoard does not show when you unlock the screen. This is the same as opening OnBoard Preferences and finding that checkbox. Sometimes that option gets enabled and it doesn't change back.

Comment: `That is the same as the option under System Settings / Universal Access.`
This saved my brain, as I didn't want to remove onboard but just turning it off wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

On login page of ubuntu, click human icon on the top bar then uncheck onscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I opened onboard only one time, and ever since then it showed up when I was unlocking no matter what settings were set to.

I ended up uninstalling, I mean, I have never needed to, nor foresee a reason that I would ever need to use it.

So if you don't think you'll use it, I would recommend uninstalling. It's not really a fix, but you won't have to deal with it.

Comment: Kopkins, for that problem, see my answer. (It's an option in Onboard Settings that gets turned on unexpectedly). Uninstalling solves it too, of course :)