# How do I disable the on-screen keyboard in the unlock screen?

Tags: keyboard, lock-screen, orca

Somehow, I activated the on-screen keyboard (Onboard) in the unlock screen and I can't deactivate it now. I've restarted the computer, but it's still there in the unlock screen.

How can I deactivate the on-screen keyboard in the unlock screen?

Comment: This is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/62964/55343

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**GUI method**

Search for *Onboard settings* from the gnome-shell overview.

Under *General* tab and *Desktop integration* heading, uncheck the option *Show Onboard when unlocking the screen*.

[image]

**Command-line method**

[Thanks to fossfreedom's answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/89967/25798)

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set apps.onboard xembed-onboard false
```

If the above is not working, try this one:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
```

worked for me (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I'm not sure how I activated these settings in the first place though.

Comment: It's also happens to me, and I did a bug report. Please, go to this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/986843 and tick in the green text "is this bug affecting you?" to indicate that it also happens to you. Thank you =)

Comment: Note that this isn't specific to Gnome Shell. I was bitten by this bug in Unity.

Comment: Scott Severance: Ok, I take into account in the bug report =) thank you.

Answer (score 26):

In the Dash, open `Onboard Settings`.

[image]

Unmark *Show Onboard when unlocking the screen*.

[image]

Done.

Answer (score 2):

On login page of ubuntu, click human icon on top bar then un check onscreen keyboard.