# On-screen keyboard shows up on resume

Tags: orca

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the on-screen keyboard in the unlock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84050/how-do-i-disable-the-on-screen-keyboard-in-the-unlock-screen)

I recently got Ubuntu 11.10 and I was looking through the programs and saw Onboard and didn't know what is was so I clicked on it. I know now that it is an onscreen keyboard and I don't need it so I quit it. I left my computer for a while and came back shook the mouse and when it goes to the login screen to resume the Onboard keyboard is there and I can't close it. So I logged in and ended the process from the system monitor. I left again and when I came back it did the same thing and when I checked system monitor after logging in Onboard didn't know up so it wasn't running. How do I get it to go away?

p.s. If you need screenshots I'll post some when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried in preferences? Check the Startup Applications and see if orca is enabled.

Comment: Yes jokerdino it is the same thing thank you both for your answers I really appreciate it.                                               Jake